# How can i sum up of all the prices which are in span class="total"?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a two section on my page, one for processor and the other one
is Ram, I am fetching prices from database using ajax how can i add
all those prices which are in the span class="total"?

[image: As you can see in this picture]

```
<td>
    <span class="multTotalRam total" id="show_productRam" readonly value="">650.00</span>
</td>

<td>
    <span class="multTotalPro total" id="show_productPro" readonly value="">1050.00</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, also there is no reason to have readonly on a span

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, i have never do this before, this is new topic for me

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through class and add all value one by one.

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat($(this).text()); // 
});

console.log('sum', sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <span class="multTotalRam total" id="show_productRam" readonly value="">650.00</span>
</td>

<td>
  <span class="multTotalPro total" id="show_productPro" readonly value="">1050.00</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried / tested but perhaps you could try the following

```
let total=0;
document.querySelectorAll('span.total').forEach(span=>{
    total+=parseFloat( span.innerText )
})
alert( total )
```